# Install python pymysql on win7

Tags: python, mysql

So I am completely unfamiliar with python and wanted to install pymysql.

This is the actual command I typed in cmd and the response I got:

```
C:\>d:\python27\python d:\pymysql\setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pymysql\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I have python 2.7.8 and MySQL 6.x

I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2012/cs2316_fall/presentations/HOWTO_install_pymysql_windows.pdf).

I haven't tried to search for the error message but have not found anything. Maybe some of you guys can help?

Comment: You'd better try to learn how to use Google

Comment: @Raptor thanks, by the way I used nearly the same query, but not a useful result: https://www.google.hu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pymssql%20importerror%20no%20module%20named%20setuptools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install setuptools  from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/5.8) first, and then try to install pymysql again.

Comment: Thanks, by the way is there possibly a complete package kinda thing, that solves it in one go and you don't have to install everything individually?

Comment: @Sesertin After installation of setuptools, you can try easy_install. Here is link of instruction. https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html  If this helps, don't forget to accept it as an answer. :)